# Get specific value from a Array of JSON object and push it to another array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js, I have an Array of JSON Object, How can I push the 'c' and 'd' to selected1 and push the '88' and '66' to selected2?

```
export default {
 arr:[{
    "name": "a",
    "options": [{
        label: "b",
        value: 9,
        foodoption: [{ label: "c", value: 8 }, { label: "d", value: 6 }],
        selected1: [],
        show: false
      },

    ]},
    {
      "name": "aa",
      "options": [{
          label: "bb",
          value: 9,
          foodoption: [{ label: "cc", value: 88 }, { label: "dd", value: 66 }],
          selected2: [],
          show: false
        },
      ]}
  ]
```

expect get:

```
selected1:[c,d]

selected2:[88,66]
```

I try to use vue.js to get the value in the view:

```
<div v-for="(obj, index) in arr" :key="index" >
     <div v-for="(opt, index) in obj.foodoption" :key="index">
         {{ opt.label }} {{ opt.value}}
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I get each expects item by JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a JS question, you don't need VueJS to do that. Simply use a combination of dot and bracket notation to access the `foodoption` value in your `arr`, and then use `Array.prototype.map` to return the desired values based on the key (`label` or `value`):

```js
const arr = [{
  "name": "a",
  "options": [{
      label: "b",
      value: 9,
      foodoption: [{ label: "c", value: 8 }, { label: "d", value: 6 }],
      selected1: [],
      show: false
    },

  ]},
  {
    "name": "aa",
    "options": [{
        label: "bb",
        value: 9,
        foodoption: [{ label: "cc", value: 88 }, { label: "dd", value: 66 }],
        selected2: [],
        show: false
      },
    ]}
];

const selected1 = arr[0].options[0].foodoption.map(opt => opt.label);
const selected2 = arr[1].options[0].foodoption.map(opt => opt.value);

console.log(selected1);
console.log(selected2);
```